# Python Seaborn Distplot Y value corresponding to a given X value

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, point, seaborn

I need to plot points on a Seaborn distplot corresponding to certain X values such that they fall either on the density curve or below it.  Here is a distplot from the following URL:
[From the Seaborn site - distplot examples](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html#seaborn.distplot)

Here is an image with the code:

[image]

So for example, in the plot shown above, I need to determine programmatically what is the Y axis value corresponding to the X value of 0 that falls on the density curve.  From the figure, it seems like it is somewhere around 0.37.  How can I get that in my program?

Assuming that can be done, then how can I show it in the plot shown, i.e., what line of code will show that.  I am translating a set of R visualizations to Python.  The following plot in R shows what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

See the points shown on the curve?  There are many point values to be drawn, but if you help me draw one, I can try to do the rest.  I am a beginning user of both Matplotlib and Seaborn packages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]

In order to obtain the y coordinate for a point on the kde curve of the distplot, you can use the underlying data of the curve. You can get the data from the line plot using the [`get_data`](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.get_data) method of the line.
You can then interpolate the data on the point(s) you are interested in, using e.g. [`numpy.interp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html).

```
import seaborn.apionly as sns
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(0)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.randn(100)
ax = sns.distplot(x, hist_kws={"ec":"k"})
data_x, data_y = ax.lines[0].get_data()

xi = 0 # coordinate where to find the value of kde curve
yi = np.interp(xi,data_x, data_y)
print ("x={},y={}".format(xi, yi)) # prints x=0,y=0.3698
ax.plot([0],[yi], marker="o")
plt.show()
```

---

Being asked in the comments about how to obtain this solution:

Start with the problem. We have a distplot and we want to draw a point at a certain point on its kde curve.

1. Look at the documentation; does the distplot function have an argument that does what we want? Unfortunately not.
2. Does the function return an object? Yes. Is it the curve? Unfortunately not. Instead it's a matplotlib axes. (finding that out with `type()`)
3. Find out what a matplotlib axes is; read [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html). Uff, it's pretty heavy, but we stumble upon a method `axes.get_lines()`; since the curve should be a line, that should help.
4. Find out what those lines are: They are [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html) objects. Again looking at the documentation we find that there is a method `get_data`. So now we have the data of the curve. Great!
5. At this point it would be even better if we had a function we could call with our x value to receive the corresponding y value. Now it seems, we need to find that function by ourselves.
6. So given `x` and `y` data of the curve, how do we find the y value of a given x value? Since the data is discrete, we need to interpolate. Looking around for "interpolate" & "python" eventually brings us to `numpy.interp`. So this provides us with the coordinates we need to draw a point.
7. Find out how to draw a point. Well that's easy. Lots of examples for that around.

That's it.

Comment: This works well.  I have a follow up question.  How does one go about knowing this?  Or, how did you know this?  Is there a structured path that you followed or this is hard earned knowledge acquired by experience?  I am an experienced programmer new to Python and newer to Seaborn, but have been programming for awhile now.  Is there a method to acquiring this knowledge?

Comment: I updated the answer to include how the solution is obtained starting at the problem description. It may help to understand the process.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent explanation of the process.  Kind regards.  Bharat

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me with my problem. If anyone has any issue with `ax.lines[0].get_data()` try `ax.get_lines()[0].get_data()`.