# Getting (x, y) pairs of a seaborn FacetGrid with distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm plotting a cumulative distribution of some data following the example in the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

sns.set(style="ticks", color_codes=True)

bins = np.arange(0, 65, 5)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="day", height=4, aspect=.5)
g = g.map(sns.distplot, "total_bill", bins=bins, hist_kws={"histtype":"stepfilled"})
```

[image]

Now I'd like to get the y values corresponding to each bin. How can I do that?

A similar questions on SO ([Get data points from Seaborn distplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37374983/get-data-points-from-seaborn-distplot/37375147)) suggests to use `get_data()` from the plot axis lines.

I tried

```
for ax in g.axes[:,0]:
    lines = ax.get_lines()
```

and I get that `lines` is `<a list of 0 Line2D objects>`. This means there's no lines to call `get_data()`.

Another question ([Python Seaborn Distplot Y value corresponding to a given X value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43565892/python-seaborn-distplot-y-value-corresponding-to-a-given-x-value)) suggests to use `get_height()` from the axis patches.

I tried

```
for ax in g.axes[:,0]:
    values = [h.get_height() for h in ax.patches]
```

and I get an `AttributeError: 'Polygon' object has no attribute 'get_height'`. Indeed, I can't see any `get_height` method in the `Polygon` [matplotlib API](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Polygon.html).

Ideas?

UPDATE:

After some investigation I found out that having the argument `hist_kws={"histtype":"stepfilled"}` invalidates the way of getting data from the bars via `get_height()`.

Comment: Testing with the latest version of seaborn, `for ax in g.axes[0]: values = [h.get_height() for h in ax.patches]` seems to give all the heights of the rectangles. Maybe you have more objects in your plot? Maybe you should filter out the rectangles?

Comment: What happens if you `type(h)`? `ax.patches` is a list of objects of type `<class 'matplotlib.patches.Polygon'>`, and they have no `get_height()` method.

Comment: Does `for ax in g.axes.ravel():    lines = ax.get_lines()` work for you?

Comment: @st1led I get `<class 'matplotlib.patches.Rectangle'>` for all of them (seaborn 0.10).

Comment: @QuangHoang: `ax.get_lines` is a list of four (because I have four graphs in the facet I guess) objects of type `<class 'matplotlib.cbook.silent_list'>`, each being `<a list of 0 Line2D objects>`. Since there's no `Line2D` objects, I can't perform `get_data()`.

@JohanC: this is weird. I am using seaborn 0.10.0 but I get these `Polygon` objects rather than `Rectangle`. I'll see if I can further minimize the MWE I posted and find out what's going on.

Comment: I got what was causing me the problem -- I omitted it in the MWE because I thought it wasn't relevant. When calling `g.map()` I use the argument `hist_kws={"histtype":"stepfilled"}` which seems to turn the `Rectangle` into `Polygon` and screwing up the way to retrieve data.